# JsPDF generates a blank PDF

Tags: javascript, jspdf, html2pdf

I am using: [jsPDF](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jspdf) to generate pdf from html in the **server side**

I have installed the following packages:

```
"html2canvas": "^1.3.2",
"jspdf": "^2.3.1",
```

makePdf.ts

```
const { jsPDF } = require("jspdf");  
const doc = new jsPDF();
  
doc.html('<p>Hola Mundo!</p>');
doc.save("export.pdf");
```

The issue is I am getting a blank pdf document and I don't know how to fix this issue.

When I write a plain text (i.e doc.text('Hola Mundo!', 10, 10)) it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to replace ".html" with ".fromHTML". Therefore it will look something like this:

```js
const { jsPDF } = require("jspdf");  
const doc = new jsPDF();
  
doc.fromHTML('<p>Hola Mundo!</p>');
doc.save("export.pdf");
```

Comment: i don't think `fromHTML` is supported in 2.3.1, because it was deprecated.